# sublime: build system variables not working

Tags: c++, mingw, sublimetext2

I have tried using the default build system for C++. It seems the variable `$file` is messed up. Here's how build script looks like:

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

  "variants":
  [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And, whenever I am trying to compile, I get the errors:

```
 [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'C:\\Users\\Ankit Mongia\\workspace\\HelloWorld\\HelloWorld.cpp', u'-o', u'C:\\Users\\Ankit Mongia\\workspace\\HelloWorld${file_base_name}']]
[dir:  C:\Users\Ankit Mongia\workspace\HelloWorld]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Ankit Mongia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ankit Mongia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\; E:\Development\MinGW\bin\]
[Finished]
```

I don't understand why the script is messing up the path format of windows? it has got double backslashes up in "cmd" and single backslash in "path". And I dont understand the "u" literal in "cmd".
I am not sure how important that "variants" is, I don't have bash executable on my windows machine. I am unable to understand the compilation error.

Comment: Did you save the file? Did you try and prepend `"echo"` to see what you're command looks like? Variants can be selected using Ctrl-Shift-B, but since you don't have bash, there's no need to use it.